# HackerRank Strange Counter

Tags: c++, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I wrote a solution to [HackerRank Strange Counter](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/strange-code):

> The counter counts down in cycles.  At *t* = 1, the counter displays the number 3.  At each subsequent second, the number displayed by the counter decrements by 1.
>
> Each time the counter reaches 1, the number becomes 2× the initial number for that countdown cycle.
>
> The sequence goes:
>
> > 3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, …
>
> Print the value of the counter the time *t*, where 1 ≤ *t* ≤ 10<sup>12</sup>.  For example, if *t* = 4, print `6`.

My code works for inputs up to 100 million but when I enter number 1 billion or greater then I get TLE.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long n;

    cin >> n;


    long long  x = 3;
    long long count = x;
    for(long long i = 2; i <= n;i++)
    {
        count--;
        if(i == n)
        {
            break;
        }

    else if(count == 1)
        {    i++;
             x = 2*x;
             count = x;

        }
    }

    cout << count;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Style

In C++, don't `#include<stdio.h>` or any other C-style `.h` file.  `#include <iostream>` should be sufficient for all of your I/O needs.  It is customary to put a space after `#include`.

In general, [`using namespace std` is bad practice](//stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1157100).  Here, you actually wasted more characters writing the "shortcut" than writing out `std::cin` and `std::cout` like you should have.

In the problem statement, the input is called *t*.  Why did you name your variable `n` in your code then?

`x` is a cryptic variable name.  I suggest `countdown_init`.

It is customary to end the output with a newline.  If you don't, then in Unix shells the command prompt would immediately follow the output on the same line, which looks ugly.

### Algorithm

The reason your program exceeds the time limit is simple: this loop counts up to `n`, one step at a time.

> ```
> for(long long i = 2; i <= n;i++)
> ```

Your algorithm is thus said to be O(*t*).

To speed it up, you need to fast-forward through entire countdown sequences.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    long long countdown_init, t;
    std::cin >> t;
    for (countdown_init = 3; t > countdown_init; countdown_init *= 2) {
        t -= countdown_init;
    }
    std::cout << (countdown_init - t + 1) << '\n';
}
```

This solution would be O(log *t*), since it only loops once per countdown cycle.  We can estimate the amount of work by rounding up *t* to the last *t* of each cycle:

$$\begin{align}
t \approx&\ 3\ (\underbrace{1 + 2 + 4 + \ldots + 2^{c}}_{c\ \textrm{cycles}}) \\
  \approx&\ 3 \cdot 2^{c+1} \\
  =&\ 6 \cdot 2^c
\end{align}$$

The number of cycles \$c\$ is therefore

$$c \approx \log_2 \frac{t}{6} = O(\log t)$$